# Capturing scroll events on third party websites?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, usability

I am trying to compare scrolling behavior on a mobile vs desktop website. The plan is to let participants scroll on a mobile phone and desktop in a lab respectively for x minutes. Therefore, I have full control over the devices.
How do I capture the scrolling events on third-party websites such as Reddit? Google Chrome has a feature called [performance insights](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/performance-insights/) to track user behavior, but it does not record scrolling.
What are some viable alternatives to record the scrolling of users on mobile and desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to create a [bookmarklet](https://dev.to/mattkenefick/bookmarklet-for-injecting-scripts-onto-a-page-4gkg) that injects a tracking script into the website you want to track.